# How to simplify this css star rating?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to simply this star rating that is in a cshtml page of my project. I would like to not have to have all this code in my View. It takes a view model's value of a score and decides how many checked stars to display. Does anyone know how to make this better?

```
 @if (Model.Score>= 100)
                {
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                }
                else if(Model.Score>= 80)
                {
                    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                }
                else if(Model.Score>=60)
                {
                    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                }
                else if(Model.Score>=40)
                {
                    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                }
                 else if(Model.Score>=20)
                {
                    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                }
                 else if(Model.Score<20 && Model.Score>=0)
                {
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do a loop using calculated number of starts checked `n` and unchecked (`5 - n`)

```html
@{n = Math.Floor(Math.Min(1, Model.Score/100) * 5)}

@for(var i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>}

@for(var i = 0; i <= 5 - n); i++)
    {<span class="fa fa-star" span>}
```

or better yet figure out the `checked` class in the same loop

```html
@for(var i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {<span class="fa fa-star @(@Model.Score <= i * 5 ? 'checked' : '')"></span>}
```

Comment: Hello this looks good, however the Math.min and floor aren't being recognised in my cshtml file

Comment: I think because they need to be capitalized (nod lower-case as in js). But the second option is probably better anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can create `score/20` checked stars and the remaining will be unchecked stars.

```js
const score = 60;
const checkedStars = Math.floor(score / 20);
const uncheckedStars = 5 - checkedStars;

for (let i = 0; i < checkedStars; i++) {
  document.body.innerHTML += `<i class="fa fa-star checked"></i>`
}

for (let i = 0; i < uncheckedStars; i++) {
  document.body.innerHTML += `<i class="far fa-star "></i>`
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Comment: @culdaffe Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Hello, would I put this in my cshtml page or in my site js?

Comment: This is in JavaScript, so put along side other js code. Please let me know if this works or else I will remove my answer. @culdaffe